# How can I use Typed package in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, db2

I want to use the `idm_db` package with Typescript and React.
In its document, it only explains `nodejs` and also it does not support types.
Luckily, there is `@types/ibm_db` and I think it supports types, but I cannot figure out how to use this one.

In nodejs,

```js
var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');

ibmdb.open("DATABASE=<dbname>;HOSTNAME=<myhost>;UID=db2user;PWD=password;PORT=<dbport>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", function (err,conn) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  conn.query('select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);

    conn.close(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });
  });
});
```

[node ibm_db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db)

Following this one, I just changed first line,
from `var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');` to `import * asibmdb from 'ibm_db'`.
But, it keeps throwing an error related to webpack.(I don't use webpack at this point). It compiles, but page is showing the error messages.

So, my question is, how can I use this package in React and Typescript way?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
It throws lots of errors and I am posting errors that I think it may cause.

```
  28 |                      path.resolve(__dirname, '../installer/clidriver/lib');
  29 | }
  30 | 
> 31 | var odbc = require("bindings")("odbc_bindings")
  32 |   , SimpleQueue = require("./simple-queue")
  33 |   , util = require("util")
  34 |   , Readable = require('stream').Readable
```

```
199 |   // Avoids an infinite loop in rare cases, like the REPL
  200 |   dir = process.cwd();
  201 | }
> 202 | if (
      | ^  203 |   exists(join(dir, 'package.json')) ||
  204 |   exists(join(dir, 'node_modules'))
  205 | ) {
```

```
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
```

Comment: What error are you getting? "keeps throwing an error", what is that error?

Comment: @basic I added some errors on the page

Comment: How did you setup your project? I am actually experiencing other issues. `npx create-react-app jayko-app --template typescript` and then `cd jayko-app npm start` works fine. Once I installed `npm install ibm_db` and did nothing else, I started getting a react declaration file error.

Comment: @chrisbyte I started with `create-reat-app --typescript`. I also had `npm install --save-dev ibm_db` and `npm install @types/ibm_db --save`. I think the declaration file error is from typescript. pure ibm_db does not have types. So I installed `@types/ibm_db`.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I might use

```
import * as ibmdb from 'ibm_db';
```

Does that help? Some reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43172907/8678978

I have the same issue when I use the `moment` package in React with typescript

Comment: I tried that one as well. Do you use `import` to use`moment` and does it work?

Comment: Yes, I would use it like `import * as moment from 'moment';`

Comment: I did, but no luck.